# How do you make multer save the file in a folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, file-upload, multer

I'm having trouble using multer to save a photo in a folder. The path of the file would be uploaded to mlab (working fine), but its supposed to grab the image from the folder I want it to grab it from, which is just not saving. When trying to look at it from the view, it throws a 404 error, due to the picture not being present in the folder. Here's my server-side controller:

```
var multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './modules/articles/client/img/'); // where to store it
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    if(!file.originalname.match(/\.(png|jpg|jpeg|pdf|gif)$/)) {
      var err = new Error();
      err.code = 'filetype'; // to check on file type
      return cb(err);
    } else {
      var day = new Date();
      var d = day.getDay();
      var h = day.getHours();
      var fileNamee = d + '_' + h + '_' + file.originalname;
      console.log("filename produced is: " + fileNamee);
      cb(null, fileNamee);
    }
  }
});

var upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: { fileSize: 20971520 } // Max file size: 20MB
}).single('myfile'); // name in form

exports.uploads = function (req, res) {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      if (err.code === 'LIMIT_FILE_SIZE') {
        res.json({ success: false, message: 'File size is too large. Max limit is 20MB' });
      } else if (err.code === 'filetype') {
        res.json({ success: false, message: 'File type is invalid. Accepted types are .png/.jpg/.jpeg/.pdf' });
      } else {
        console.log('err = ' + err);
        res.json({ success: false, message: 'File was not able to be uploaded' });
      }
    } else {
      if (!req.file) {
        var article = new Article(req.body);
        article.user = req.user;

        article.save(function (err) {
          if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
              message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
          } else {
            res.jsonp(article);
          }
        });
      }
      else if (req.file) {
        res.json({ success: true, message: 'File was uploaded!' });
      }

    }
    // Everything went fine
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine. Check your folder permissions. Make sure server is able to write to folder.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kinda new to working with meanJS and client-server work, but the img folder has chmod 755 whereas the server-side controller has chmod 644 (-rw-r--r--). I will say that if I throw print statements in the middle of the exports.upload functions and the filename function, nothing prints out. Does it have to do something with not being called?